# ng g c --module keeps giving error -Selector "src/app-{module name}" is invalid

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to create a new component for my app, and the ng cli keeps throwing a "Selector --- is invalid" message.

I'm using cli version 15.2.7

See screen shot for command details

[image: Screenshot of non-working component generation command, along with the angular version installed.]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the issue.

In your angular.json, you can set a prefix. While I was trying to get something unrelated working, I changed this value.

If you have this entry as anything but an empty string, the cli automatically tries to prepend it to the name of the component you're trying to make. Thus leading to a potentially invalid component name.

[image: screen shot of angular.json with incorrect value highlighted]